# Oracle - Apache PL/SQL Gateway Module - mod_owa - access remote server

Tags: apache, plsql, oracle11g, middleware, mod-plsql

I have an Ubuntu 13.10 VM that I've created using Vagrant. This is meant to be a local development environment for a remote application using Oracle 11g and Oracle Fusion Middleware 11g.

What I want to do is, clone the application's code repository into the local VM and "route" the requests that are made on the local VM through the server where the application is hosted (DEV), so I won't need to install the database on the local VM together with all it's packages and procedures and also Oracle Middleware.

I came across Apache PL/SQL Gateway Module (https://oss.oracle.com/projects/mod_owa/dist/documentation/modowa.htm) which it's a substitute for Oracle Middleware.

I've installed and configured **mod_owa** on the VM, but when I restarted Apache I got the following error:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 234 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: 
Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/conf.d/mod_owa.conf: 
Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_owa.so into server: libclntsh.so.11.1: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
...fail!
```

The above error makes me think that I still need to install Oracle 11g on the VM. Is there a way to bypass that error and make use of the remote server (DEV)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but yes you need Oracle client installed on your apache server.

Answer (score 0):

You need instant client with OCI (Basic): http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-100365.html

Then to simplify your running environment:

As root:
Create a file `oracle.conf` under `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`
Single line in that file with a reference you oracle lib directory (oracle client home/lib)

run `ldconfig`

And you should be good to go.